# File browser accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making a File browser using jquery. That I want to reconize which li has a class file in it. But it also reconizes sub menus as a file.

What am I doing wrong?

Jquery:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $("#accordion > li").click(function() {

                if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    // Remove the class from anything that is active
                    $("li.active").removeClass("active");
                    // And make this active
                    $(this).toggleClass("active");
                    /*$('li').removeClass('active');
                     $(this).addClass('active');*/
                }
                if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                    $('#accordion > ul').slideUp(300);
                }
                if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('file')) {
                    console.log("Is file");
                    // handle as file
                } else {
                    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
                }

            });
            $("#accordion > ul li").click(function() {
                /*$('#accordion > ul li').removeClass('active');*/
                $(this).addClass('active');
                if (false == $(this).next().is(':visible')) {
                    $('#accordion > ul li ul').slideUp(300);
                }
                if ($('li:first-child').hasClass('file')) {
                    console.log("Is file");
                } else {
                    $(this).next().slideToggle(300);
                }

            });

            $('.top:even').addClass('stripe');
            $('#accordion ul li:odd').addClass('stripe');
            $('#accordion ul li ul li:even').addClass('stripe');

        });
```

Menu:

```
                <div id="menu">

                    <ul id="accordion">
                        <li class="top">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/folder-icon.png" />Sports</a>
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/folder-icon.png" />Golf</a>
                            </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem 1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem 2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem 3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem 4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/folder-icon.png" />Cricket</a>
                            </li>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a class="file" href="#"><img src="images/pdf-icon.png" />Menuitem</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/folder-icon.png" />Football</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <li class="top">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/pdf-folder-icon.png" />Technology</a>
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="file" href="#">iPhone</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="file" href="#">Facebook</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="file" href="#">Twitter</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <li class="top">
                            <a href="#"><img src="images/pdf-folder-icon.png" />Latest</a>
                        </li>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <a class="file" href="#">Obama</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a class="file" href="#">Iran Election</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <a class="file" href="#">Health Care</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </ul>

                </div><!--- menu --->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use li:first-child attribute

Comment: That does not seem to make any difference